# Running a Xen Dapper dom0 with a Hardy domU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen

Is it possible to set up a Hardy domU on an existing Xen dom0 running Dapper? I have found many postings talking about the reverse (Dapper domU on a Hardy dom0), but I have the existing server set up with a Dapper dom0 and a few Dapper domUs. I need to set up a new domU, so I want to use a more modern LTS release. I am hesitant to upgrade the dom0, on the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" principle.

Has anyone tried this? Can I just use a 2.6.24 Xen kernel? Do I need to recompile the domU kernel to match anything in my dom0?

Or is it necessary to upgrade the dom0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use HVM, if that's an option on your hardware.  Otherwise, I'd probably install a newer xen-tools (that supports hardy installs) and just create away.  There's the possibility that Hardy doesn't support the Xen kernel that ships with dapper (stupid udev), but it's worth trying out.  If that doesn't work, you *might* be able to use the domU kernel from Hardy in just the hardy domU, but hypervisor API changes might make that a losing proposition.  Again, worth an experiment.